# How to use a class?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, pojo

I use retrofit for data transmission. And I'm confused.
I have Pojo generated classes. But I do not know how to use the **Destination** class.

```
  public class NewOrderRequest {

    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private String phone;

    public NewOrderRequest(String phone, List<Destination> destinations) 
    {
       super();
       this.phone = phone;
       this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    public String getPhone() {return phone;}

    public void setDestinations(List<Destination> destinations)
    {
    this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    }
```

**CLASS DESTINATION:**

```
public class Destination {

   @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private String lat;

    public Destination(String lat) {
    super();
    this.lat = lat;

    public String getLat() {
    return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
    }

    }
```

**USE:**

**What should I pass to the setDestination method?**

```
    NewOrderRequest newOrderRequest = new NewOrderRequest();
    newOrderRequest.setPhone("+911");
    newOrderRequest.setDestinations(????????);


    NetworkService.getInstance()
                .service()
                .newOrder(jsessionid, newOrderRequest)
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
  List<Destination> destination = null;
        destination.add();
```

Comment: Whats the issue here.... ? Just add value in your defined list like destination.add(new Destination("lat_value"));

Comment: FYI: the @SerializedName annotation is only required when the name of the JSON field is different from that of your class field. In this case you can remove it

Comment: Thanks! Now I will know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `List<Destination`. But in your attempt, you only declare the `List`, you never create one. Try this:

```
List<Destination> destination = new ArrayList<>();
destination.add(new Destination("lat"));
newOrderRequest.setDestinations(destination);
```

You also need to

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```